# iml file not created in correct root

Tags: intellij-idea

I have just installed IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 (Ultimate Edition) and noticed some strange behaviour with regards the location of where the .iml file is being created.

When opening a SpringBoot project and creat a new module, I was expecting the .iml file to be created at module i.e. alongside the pom.xml.

What I expected:

```
SpringBoot
│   SpringBoot.iml
│   └───module1
│       │   pom.xml
│       │   module1.iml
```

What it looks like:

```
SpringBoot
│   SpringBoot.iml
│   module1.iml
│   └───module1
│       │   pom.xml
│       │   ...
```

[Here are Maven setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYCF0.png)

Comment: Please attach screenshot from "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing"